# Swift Reflection of class structure rather than needing an instance of the class?

Tags: reflection, swift4

In my code, I have an array of a class that may not have any members at the point where I want to get the properties through reflection. Mirror(reflecting:) requires an instance but I'm stuck at how to deal with this if I don't have any instances yet.

Here's how Apple's documentation shows an example of reflection:

```
struct Point {
    let x: Int, y: Int
}

let p = Point(x: 21, y: 30)
print(String(reflecting: p))
// Prints "▿ Point
//           - x: 21
//           - y: 30"
```

To simplify my scenario, essentially what I want to do is mirror "Point" rather than "p".

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you give some context please? Why do you need to know get the properties via reflection?

Comment: Sure, what I'm doing is using the property names to map against column IDs in a NSTableView so that I can easily set up which columns I would like to show. I'm also taking the property names and un-camel-casing them to set the column header names. Hope this helps, and if there's a better way to do this I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to close this myself because this was just an all-round bad idea. I encourage others not to use this approach for a couple of reasons:

1. It works only if you have at least one item in an array of a class/struct
2. You are stuck with the property names as they appear in the class as your header titles

Instead, I am using logic to search through the cell identifiers which I set in the storyboard. When I find the cell identifier which matches my property name, I set the text to the value. The header of the row is set in the storyboard, so it is easily edited and (manually) formatted.

Here's the code for anyone who is interested.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

    if viewOrder!.orders.count == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    let cellIdentifier = tableColumn!.identifier.rawValue
    let orderRow = viewOrder!.orders[row]
    var text = ""
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: orderRow)
    for (name, value) in mirror.children        {
        if name == cellIdentifier {
            text = "\(value)"
        }
    }

    if let cell = orderTableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(cellIdentifier), owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView {
        cell.textField?.stringValue = text
        return cell
    } else {
        print("Didn't create cell in column \(tableColumn!.headerCell.title): \(cellIdentifier) : \(text)")
    }

    return nil

}
```

Note that the code above is optimized for reading and I'm sure it can be tighter. I am, of course, open to comments on better ways to do this.